# Bind Variable Oracle DB - R

Tags: r, oracle11g, rodbc

I'm working on some R-scripts which require the use of database queries. My IT department mentioned to me that these scripts require too much of the database (shared pool) and I should use bind-variables.

I am not very familiar with database designing, but I found out that bind variables are like variables i.e. if you use for example `and date=:var` in a statement.

Is it possible to use such statements when working with R (`RODBC`)?
Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using bind variables is a part of the SQL query you write. So I presume that when you connect to the Oracle database using `RODBC`, you can pass an valid SQL query that contains bind variable syntax, and that this would simply work.